# How import grails project to Intellij 13.1 IDEA?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I need to import a grails project to IntelliJ IDEA.

(I am very new to IntelliJ, grails, groovy).

When I try to build the project, the following error is obtained for each of
the modules:
Error:Cannot compile Groovy files: no Groovy library is defined for module ''

Would you know how I can fix this - how to correctly import the project - since I believe a Grails installation contains a Groovy library.

When I import into GGTS (as a Grails project), the project builds ok.

Answer (score 1):

Prerequisite: you need the Ultimate Edition of IntelliJ IDEA to get Grails support (see Frameworks and Technologies in the [community/ultimate edition comparison](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html))

With the Ultimate Edition you..

1. use *File/Open..* to open the project
2. click the *Configure SDK* link in the green popup that appears on the top right (*Grails SDK not found: Module 'import' has no Grails SDK. Configure SDK*)
3. create the Grails SDK
4. if the green pop up is not visible anymore you can open the *Event Log* (bottom right). There you will find the message from the pop up and you can continue at 3.

Answer (score 0):

In *Intellij 14* I have clicked right mouse button on project and choose *Open Module Settings*, then *Modules*. I have grails added before, I needed to add groovy, so *Add/Library* and choose directory with *groovy*.