# Intellig IDEA x Grails

Tags: grails, ide

I tested several IDEs for developing grails applications. Tested the [Spring IDE](http://spring.io/tools/sts/all), did not like because I thought slow and crashes every time. 
Tested by [netbeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/grails-quickstart_pt_BR.html), and the result was the same as before. 
Was reading about [IntelliJ IDEA](https://grails.org/IDEA+Integration). Current problem, even doing the command "grails integrate-with --intellij" mentioned on the website https://grails.org/IDEA+Integration not enabled the option of creating projects in grails . 
After running the command above returns nothing.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you will need the ultimate edition of IntelliJ to get grails support
- With ultimate you can simply open an existing grails project (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24711015/1262371)) or create a project from the *File/New Project...* menu.

Answer (score 2):

`grails integrate-with --intellij` creates three files in the directory (`yourproject.(iml|ipr|iws)`).  You can open the `.ipr` file with IntelliJ and have the project loaded (it might ask to convert the file).

Also you can just create new project (pick `Gradle` and then `Grails`) or you can just use the directory as existing source where you `create-app`-ed your project and IntellIj will see, that it is Grails.

**Be aware, that it will only work with the Ultimate Edition and not the Community Edition**

Comment: Even in the IDE community? According to Martin, only the ultimate version.

Comment: no this was not clear in the question so i assumed ultimate (that is what is use)